# Swift App elements not loading in time from storyBoard

Tags: swift, storyboard

I'm running in to an issue where I have a home controller which checks if the user is logged in and the presents a login controller if this fails. The problem I'm facing is occasionally the elements and their attached classes from storyBoard failed to load in time. As mentioned this is occasional behaviour. Is this normal or will I have to have a delay function before hand to wait a second before presenting the login controller?

This is happening on device testing, not simulator. If I touch the screen the elements are shown. Weird behaviour

Comment: Sounds weird. I never had problems like this. It sounds that you use elements that are still nil. Whats the error message? How do you call the present view and what are you doing in your viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear Methods?

Comment: No error message or codes. Currently just trying a delay on presenting the controller, see if that squashes it.

Comment: Call your presenting in viewDidAppear() of your ViewController. The main ViewController finished loading and can call the login view. And/or surround your presenting with DispatchQueue.main.async { } Then it will call on the main thread

Comment: This helped along with a 0.02 second delay on the presenting. Should be fine - thanks!

Comment: When it works then post your solution more visible and/or vote my comment up

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use AppDelegate to to check log in like task and redirect from there

Comment: Would normally handle it this way but I didn't want to hack the root view controller.